# add image to button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7

I have created a button in javascript and I would like to use an image for the button instead of text, but I have not yet found a way to do this. So far the sources I have referenced are not working for me for some reason. What I have so far is as follows

**Javascript**

```
var sb=doc.createElement('input');              
sb.type='button';
//sb.value='Find';
sb.src = "url(/Resources/Icons/appbar.next.rest.png)";
sb.style.height='100%';
//sb.style.width='20%';
```

where my image is locoated in the directory `/Resources/Icons/appbar.next.rest.png` in my project. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to properly use an image for a button? I am new to javascript so any links, code, or directions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for adding image to button you can change type of input from button to image:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var s = document.createElement("input");
s.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4d1ef03af32c9db6ee014c3eb11bdf6?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG";
s.type = "image";
body.appendChild(s);
```

you can modify it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6HdnU/

Comment: your code works regarding changing the type to image except that the image still does not show up, although it still acts like a button which is good.

Comment: yes, image input is button. modify it, change the value of sb.src, set the size according the width and height of image.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but only a blank box is appearing for the button instead of an image. I've tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @Raminson that works great! Although I still have an issue with loading a local image from my WP7 project using s.src. I'm not sure if you are familiar with WP7 or C# but if you happen to have any clue as to why I cannot load a local image I would certainly appreciate the input!

Comment: I have seen suggestions of using FileSystemObject to read a file locally. Do you know of a way to read a file from the locally (in my case a windows phone project) to load the image locally from the source directory?

Comment: unfortunately i haven't developed an application for Windows Phone 7 yet, I have read some articles for accessing images via WebClient API, jQuery .load method can load files well, you can try to load files by using this method, http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

```
Use input type="image", or use a button element with an <img> child.
```

for example:

```
    <input type="image" src="art/clips/eightbll.gif" 
     name="input_img" width="63" height="64">

or

    <button type="button" id="input_img"> 
    <img src="art/clips/eightbll.gif" 
     alt="Image input control" width="63" height="64">
    </button>
```

Comment: I cannot believe that this is a thing that is possible, but I tested it and it works. (At least in Firefox.) Although I have found this article which says that [input type image considered harmful](http://blog.lexity.com/blog/2011/6/18/input-typeimage-considered-harmful.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference- I never had a problem, or even noticed the server getting the image coordinates, but I suppose it could cause a problem for somone, somwhere.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this page](http://blog.lexity.com/blog/2011/6/18/input-typeimage-considered-harmful.html) which recommends against `input type="image"` it seems like using a `type="image"` could be problem if you're planning on doing anything with the button (on the server *or* in javascript.

Basically, instead of using the pure-html properties of the buttons to show the input, you should use CSS's `background-image` property.

js matching yours:

```
var sb=doc.createElement('input');              
sb.type='button';
sb.class='myImageButton';
```

and with this css:

```
input.myImageButton {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -3000px;
  background: url(/Resources/Icons/appbar.next.rest.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  /* width: 20%; */
  height: 100%;
}
```

should work.

It's probably worth pointing out that if you're not doing *anything* with the value of this button then this answer isn't really worth your time. But you had better be sure.

Comment: my solution best matches the one below except that my image is still not showing up properly, although the button remains clickable. Any ideas on how to properly point to the correct directory?

Comment: If you're going through a server (Apache or whatever) then the resource will be relative to the "document root", and since this is a `/rooted` resource identifier it should be correct no matter what. Is `/Resource...` relative to the document root or the filesystem?

Comment: its actually being used in a webbrowser control in a WP7 application. I'm creating the javascript function in a text file and loading that text file into my C# code behind, which is working correctly thus far. I have my image in my /Resources/Icons folder.

Comment: Is `/Resources/Icons` relative to the application or the filesystem? I've never written a WP app, so I don't know what's common in that situation, or even the general terminology. To test, I would recommend sticking the image in the same directory as the html file and setting `sb.style.backroundImage = "app.next.rest.png";` in the javascript.

Comment: I've got to go, but if the image exists I do recommend trying to get rid of path ambiguities while testing, you can fix them later, once you know that your code works.