# loading local file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7

I am attempting to use a javascript function to load a local file in my WP7 project. So far the following code works but it loads an image file from a web address instead of a local directory in my WP7 application ( Resources/Icons/appbar.go.rest.png). I have researched everywher to load a local image file properly from a local directory in my project but have yet to be successful. My code is as follows

Javascript

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
var s = document.createElement("input"); 
/loads image file from web address
s.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a4d1ef03af32c9db6ee014c3eb11bdf6?        s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"; 
s.type = "image"; 
body.appendChild(s);
```

As I said the above code works, but I would like to use a local image file in my project rather than the web address above. Does anyone know how to correctly implement this solution?

Comment: what ??? how's that supposed to work ?

Comment: Are you trying to load the image from the client or the server?

Comment: @c69 my javascript function is in a text file which I am calling from C# code behind in my WP7 application. This actually does work (i dunno about the first line though I am appending it to a different div).

Comment: And @Miguelr I am trying to load the image from the client side, the image is in my main WP7 project. There has got to be a way to do this, literally nothing I have tried or referenced on the web or this site works so far. I tried a restatement of my question which others have commented on and I have attempted their solutions as well without luck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135023/add-image-to-button-in-javascript/10135062#comment13019723_10135062 . Also, I have saved my image as Content because I do not think it should be Resource.

Comment: Then this problem is specific to the windows mobile app API. Sounds like WebClient is the way to do it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load the image directly from the clien't machine (remember that that javascript peace of code will run on the client's local machine). You should serve the image file as you are serving the Javascript file, then point 'src' there.

Comment: Thanks @Chango. I am actually not 'serving' my javascript code, it is in a text file that I am reading from my C# code behind in my WP7 project. The function actually does work, except for the image part. Any ideas on how I might actually be able to load a local image via javascript within my own project, or does this violate the new/current security principles?

Answer (score 0):

you can read this article which provide a solution by using `WebClient`:

Operating with image files in a Windows Phone 7 application
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/operating-image-files-windows

jQuery .load() method can load files well, but unfortunately I haven't used it on windows phone 7 environment which saves files on its Local Storage.

http://api.jquery.com/load/